# Join two absolute paths?

Tags: python

How do i join two absolute paths in Python?

e.g.

```
path1 = 'C:/folder1/folder2/'
path2 = 'D:/directory1/directory2/'
```

The desired result is: `C:/folder1/folder2/directory1/directory2/`

I tried `os.path.join` but it neglects the first path because it detects it's an absolute path. So what's the best way to join paths like this in Python?

Thank you!

Comment: trim the D: and use a + to combine the strings?

Comment: @dfundako eh, i know about that, but i wonder if there is a more pythonic way doing this.

Comment: Joining two absolute paths makes no sense. So there is unlikely to be a standard way to do it.

Comment: @dfundako If you post that as an answer, I'll downvote it. Using `+` on file paths is just wrong. And *how* would you strip the `D:` correctly?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I'm sure there is a SO post out there on how to trim the first 2 chars of a string if you want to know how.

Comment: @dfundako Congratulations, your code doesn't work on linux.

Comment: @Aran-Fey The joke's on you. The code I write rarely works on any operating system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, I would use `os.path.splitdrive` combined with a strip of the separator

```
import os

path1 = 'C:/folder1/folder2/'
path2 = 'D:/directory1/directory2/'

seps = os.sep+os.altsep if os.altsep else os.sep
path3 = os.path.join(path1,os.path.splitdrive(path2)[1].lstrip(seps))  # handles / and \ as separators on windows

print(path3)
```

result:

```
C:/folder1/folder2/directory1/directory2/
```

(if the second path is a relative path, it also works)

The `seps = os.sep+os.altsep if os.altsep else os.sep` line allows to be compatible with systems with no alternate separators (Linux). This solution works on Windows & Linux, `os.splitdrive` is a dummy on Linux (returning a tuple with empty first element)

Comment: Thanks about this, though i will have to make my code run on both linux and windows. So would you prefer i have two methods, one for windows and one for linux than just call these 2 separately by detecting the OS?

Comment: Ask yourself if the linux problem is really the same?  The concept of drives is totally different.  You can create symbolic links to create any directory structure you want.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Simple, clean and native. Thanks for the answer, this is awesome. (it makes me wonder to rewrite my whole script with your solution in mind)

Answer (score 15):

Use the [`pathlib` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to make the 2nd path relative and join it with the first one:

```
from pathlib import Path

path1 = Path('C:/folder1/folder2/')
path2 = Path('D:/directory1/directory2/')

path3 = path1 / path2.relative_to(path2.anchor)
# result: C:\folder1\folder2\directory1\directory2
```

---

To visualize what's happening, let's look at some intermediate output.

[`Path.anchor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.anchor) gives you the drive letter (or `/` on linux) of an absolute path. If the path is relative, it returns the empty string:

```
>>> path2.anchor
'D:\\'
>>> Path('foo').anchor
''
```

We can use this with [`Path.relative_to`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.relative_to) to turn `path2` into a relative path. If it was already relative, it won't be affected by this operation:

```
>>> path2.relative_to(path2.anchor)
WindowsPath('directory1/directory2')
>>> Path('foo').relative_to('')
WindowsPath('foo')
```

Finally, now that we have a relative path, it can trivially be combined with `path1` with the `/` operator.

Comment: this works only in python 3. And if the second directory is relative, it "eats" the root dir. But yes, works. it's also good because you don't have to strip the separators,

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Code supports relative paths now.

Comment: @Aran-Fey a nice solution, thanks, i'll remember this. Though i was avoiding the use of external libraries as i am writing this code for an extension of another software.

Comment: `Pathlib` isn't an external library. The only limitation is that it doesn't run on python 2. but as Blender answer states, you can get a backport.

Comment: @Aran-Fey exactly.. i should have noted that i must use python 2.7 :( - But i really like it.. it's very easy to understand, and i learned something today from you. Thanks for that!